# How to use filter array to filter data from an API call?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Trying to make a logic app work but just can't seem to finish off the last step - I have had a similar logic app working in the past with these steps but for the life of me i cannot remember the final steps to get it functional.

Would appreciate any help anyone can give. I've included a screenshot + some code below.

[Logic app flow Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL8vK.png)

I have redacted some of the code for obvious reasons. Hopefully, it is enough for you to get a general feel for what is happening.

Every step works fine apart from the filter array which errors, I've tried a few combinations of the filter array but with no luck.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Filter_array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['data']",
                    "where": "@contains(item(), body('Select'))"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Select": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Query"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Send_Data": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": "@{items('For_each')}",
                            "headers": {
                                "Log-Type": "REDACTED"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureloganalyticsdatacollector']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/api/logs"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Filter_array')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Filter_array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "headers": {
                        "Authorization": "API-Token REDACTED"
                    },
                    "method": "GET",
                    "queries": {
                        "start_date": "@variables('startDate')"
                    },
                    "uri": "REDACTED"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Http"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "startDate",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@{addDays(utcnow(), -5, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@body('HTTP')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "body": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "data": {

                                       REDACTED      
                             
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "statusCode": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HTTP": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Run_query_and_list_results": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "REDACTED",
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azuremonitorlogs']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/queryData",
                    "queries": {
                        "resourcegroups": “REDACTED”,
                        "resourcename": "REDACTED",
                        "resourcetype": "REDACTED",
                        "subscriptions": "REDACTED",
                        "timerange": "Last 7 days"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Select": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@body('Run_query_and_list_results')?['value']",
                    "select": "@item()?['checkpoint_s']"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Run_query_and_list_results": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Select"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Hour",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
REDACTED
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a screenshot of what the above code produces in the filter array

[Filter Array Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9KUu.png)

Breakdown of what happens:

1. I do an API call for data, I put this through parse JSON. (this part works fine - unless there is something wrong with the parse JSON definitions but I don't think there is)
2. I then do a lookup in log analytics and put this into a list using select (this part works fine)
3. Then I compare these two data sets and filter out the ones that are already present based on a specific field in the API data against the output from the select. (I believe this is the problem area)
4. I finally put the output from the filter into log analytics (this part works fine)

---

Here is what the data from the Parse JSON roughly looks like (just the layout without any real data)

```
[
 {
  DATA,
  "checkpoint": "UNIQUECODE",
  DATA
 },
 {
  DATA,
  "checkpoint": "UNIQUECODE",
  DATA
 }
]
```

Here is the list that come out of the select statement that needs to be compared against to remove already present records:

```
[
 "UNIQUECODE",
 "UNIQUECODE",
 "UNIQUECODE"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured out an elegant solution to the problem.

[image]

```
"Filter_array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['data']",
                    "where": "@not(contains(body('Select'), item()?['Checkpoint']))"
                }
```

I hope this helps anyone else who is using the filter array.